# Contents inside form_tag is not getting displayed in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I am creating a simple app in ROR , I find that what ever is given insidem my

```
<% form_tag({:action => :formcheck}, :multipart => true ) do %>
 .
 .
 .
<% end %>
```

but when I close the form_tag immediately everything inside the form is getting displayed correctly .

```
 <% form_tag({:action => :formcheck}, :multipart => true ) do %>
 <% end %>
```

I just need to know why the contents are not getting displaced .

I am using Rails version 4.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put '='

```
<%= form_tag({:action => :formcheck}, :multipart => true ) do %>
```

Comment: Could you pleas explain , why that `=` needs to be given in front of form ?

Comment: Please look inot the guides I have posted it will require to put = as not only form tag any view tags required `<%=` like 'text_field_tag', ''check_box_tag....... all required <%= not only <% it is how the way to call the methods in ActionView

Comment: Otherwise <form>..</form> tag will not add into html page.

Answer (score 0):

Please look into this http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

```
 <%= form_tag({:action => :formcheck}, :multipart => true ) do %>
  Form contents
 <% end %>
```